# How to install graphics and sound driver again?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics

One of my friends, when trying to make an USB speaker work in ubuntu 11.10+gnome 3.2+no graphics card HP machine, accidentally removed the pulseaudio driver as well as the graphics driver. So after the boot, it gives a blank screen. I tried to remove and install xorg, but it did not help. Can anyone help please?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generalist way of doing things because you neglected to include hardware information, so this is a catch-all answer.

[Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

[ATI Driver info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

[Nvidia Driver info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

[User Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)

You will almost certainly need to boot to recovery mode to install the drivers. To be honest, it may be easier to back up your data and do a fresh install.